# Using a device with external power and receive data from the CAN bus

Tags: electrical, battery, obd-ii, obd

I want to keep a device in `always on` situation in the car.

I do not want the device to drain the car battery.

The car is used at least once in two days and the current consumption of my device is not that huge < 500mA .

**Wiring** :

I plan to keep the OBD port's `+12V` **disconnected**, connect the `OBD GND` to my device's `GND` and the **data lines** to my device then power my device with an **external battery.** . I will use the 12v DC output of it.

Example of an external battery : https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07P6V7SZH/ref=sr_1_19?keywords=power+akku+generator&qid=1581438260&sr=8-19

Wire the external battery such that it's `+` line connects my device and `-` line connects to the `OBD GND` which is now shared with my device's `GND`.

Do you see any issues with that wiring ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104341/discussion-on-question-by-ali-somay-using-a-device-with-external-power-and-recei).

Answer (score 1):

I have built the device and it is working perfectly fine, there are no issues at all.

I have also added a buffer with a capacitor (10000 uF) so I could switch between the car battery and external battery seamlessly with a DPDT switch, this also works very fine.

From my experience it is quite safe to build a circuit like this.
I didn't experience any significant inrush current in my configuration.